# Ошибка в C++ как устранить

Tags: c++, c

Пытаюсь скомпилировать программу, но выдаёт ошибку ***undefined reference to `__imp_gets_s'***

Заголовочные файлы такие:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <Windows.h>
```

Ругается на  такие строки:

```
gets_s(collection[i].title, 49);
gets_s(collection[i].genre, 49);
gets_s(collection[i].platform, 49);
```

...
...

Comment: Заменить `gets_s` на `fgets`...

Answer (score -1):

Нужно добавить заголовочный файл

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

в список инклудов для препроцессора.

`gets_s()` - функция [из stdio.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets), следовательно он необходим.

Кроме того, `get_s()` c сигнатурой `char *gets_s( char *str, rsize_t n )` - это из C11, поэтому стоит удостовериться что вы компилируете\линкуете код согласно этому стандарту C.

Comment: ошибка не исчезла

Comment: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAiPm2z.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `__imp_gets_s'

Comment: Ошибка при линковке, а не при компиляции, так что `stdio` ни при чем.

Comment: @Mikhailo `stdio` - часть ответа. C11 - вторая часть. Многие IDE имеют настройки линковки в зависимости от компиляции по определенному стандарту. Я думаю, что проблема именно в этом. Так как конкретная IDE - и даже вообще как это компилируется не указано – я написал общий совет о C11. Добавил слово "линкуете" в ответ.